# Session not destroying?

Tags: php, session

Whenever I try to log in with a different user, I see that the username hasn't changed, it means $_SESSION['username'] haven't changed either, so what's wrong in my logout.php script?

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION = array(); 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
ob_start();
ob_end_flush();

header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: You need to unset the sessions's name itself.

Comment: Try `unset($_SESSION['username']);`

Comment: tried unset($_SESSION['username']);, didn't work

Comment: Can you post your login script? Is it possible you are doing an odd check there that prevents you from setting $_SESSION['username'] there?

Comment: @user2624407 You need to post your full code then. If `$_SESSION['username'] = $username` has not been declared yet, then you won't be able to unset it, if it hasn't been assigned.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/1qo5j2 lol i just realised i need to change from if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 } to simply $_SESSION['username'] = $username; EDIT:Still didn't work lol

Comment: @user2624407 As per my comment ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-It didn't work dude...

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the session cookie too, something like this, [from the reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Another good reference, the [PHP Session Introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) mentioned by George Brighton in the comments.

Comment: PHP does it for you - it's (usually) how sessions are implemented. Bed time reading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: Your php.ini probably has cookies turned on by default ... that is how a session typically persists from one call to the next. Unless you did something explicit to persist sessions some other way, in which case, you need to kill the session in the other way.

Comment: @user2624407 See my comments under your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The session is a array... I see no sense in what you are doing.

The correct would not be this way? ..

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['anything'] = array();
```

and now

```
session_destroy();
```

or

```
unset($_SESSION['anything']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with unset before session_destroy():

unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();

The first destroy data saved in the session. The last destroy COOKIE session ID.